# Elasticsearch cluster connection via Java API when master node fails

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I have an Elasticsearch cluster of 10 nodes. While connecting to the cluster via the Java API, I only connect to the master node.

```
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("masterNode"), 9300));
```

If the master node fails, will my program automatically connect to the next master node? What if I have to restart the Java program after the initial master node fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **TransportClient** client, there is a **sniff** setting for client:

1. **client.transport.sniff** mode is **false**, the **client** will only try to connect the configured **IPs**, as:

   > addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("masterNode"), 9300));
2. **client.transport.sniff** mode is **true**, the **client** will firstly to connect to configured **IPs**, and by **stats** API to discover cluster available data nodes to dynamically add new hosts and remove old ones.(Notice: if your **cluster** with your **client app** has different network, there will be an issue to connect to cluster data node), as:

   > Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
   >           .put("client.transport.sniff", true).build();
   >   TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);

So as your question, when **sniff** settings is **true** and they are under same network, your connected node failed, it's still can connect to **cluster**.

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/5.0/transport-client.html

Comment: What is the name of the `sniff` setings which I will put here: `Settings settings = Settings.builder().put().build();`